# What Photoshop CS5 Book Describes Making Images From Scratch?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, book

Can someone direct me to a photoshop cs5 book that details the image making process from beginning to end ie showing how to make an image from scratch, best techniques etc Please share why you think this book is good and why you recommend the particular book.

Comment: Do you mean digital painting, image editing/processing.. or what in particular?

Comment: image processing and making like buttons vector art etc

Comment: Look at u tube also...there are lots of free tutorials and I've learned lots from watching not just reading.

Comment: When referring to a URL it is generally best to provide the *actual* URL rather than abbreviated "chat" text.

Answer (score 1):

The most approachable and comprehensive books that cover what you're looking for are "Photoshop CS5 On-on-One" by Deke McLelland, and "Photoshop Classic Effects" by Scott Kelby. Both are extremely readable and don't get bogged down in boring detail (there's plenty of detail, but it's never boring!). Work through those two and you'll know more about Photoshop than 99% of the Photoshop users out there, and you'll be able to move up from there to develop your own personal style.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Do those books teach you best practices and things like that or is it more of a reference type book?

Comment: They're full of best practices! Both are "learn by doing" type books, and I frequently recommend them because they are easy to learn from and groove in good ways of doing things. That said, there are often many ways to accomplish almost anything you want to do in Photoshop. You'll find as you get more into it that NOBODY (except maybe Ben Willmore!) knows everything there is to know about Photoshop; not even the engineers who build it. It's an adventure that never stops... :-)